# NextJS storybook can't find the storybook-addon-next. Adding storybook-addon-next brakes storybook

Tags: next.js, storybook, storybook-addon

When I add storybook-addon-next to Storybook `main.js` file it brakes the storybook and stopping working. When I run `yarn storybook` I having a error where it says `utils.js` cannot be found under **project's parent folder** - *not the project's node_modules but it is looking for it under parent folder*.

Here is my config file:

```js
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],

  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
    'storybook-addon-next',
  ],

  framework: '@storybook/react',
  core: {
    builder: '@storybook/builder-webpack5',
  },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is you need to specify `next.config.js` file to `storybook-addon-next` because otherwise it is looking parent folders. I don't know the reason.

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],

addons: [
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],

  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
    // 'storybook-addon-next',
    {
      name: 'storybook-addon-next',
      options: {
        nextConfigPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../next.config.js'),
      },
    },
  ],

  framework: '@storybook/react',
  core: {
    builder: '@storybook/builder-webpack5',
  },
```

And I had to downgrade NextJS Version to @12.1.4. But I don't know if it's related to problem.

Comment: it's the `main.js` file where you add these